# Php code does not send query to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I am trying to update my database using ajax, but I cannot seem to understand why the php code does not update the database. The script:

```
function Insert () {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject) {
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST","list_insert.php");
            XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
                    var returnedData = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                    var messageDiv = document.getElementById('messageDiv');
                    messageDiv.innerHTML = returnedData;
                }
            }
            var item = document.getElementById('items').value;
            var desc = document.getElementById('description').value;

            var data = item + '|' + desc + '|';

            XMLHttpRequestObject.send("data=" + data);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is the php code for list_insert:

```
<?php
    include "function_list.php";
    $myData = $_POST['data'];
    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    list($items,$description) = explode ('|',$myData);

    $statement = "INSERT INTO record ";
    $statement .= "(items,description) ";
    $statement .= "VALUES (";
    $statement .=  "'".$items."', '".$description."')";
    print $statement;
    insert($statement);
    print "done";
?>
```

My php function to insert into the db (function_list):

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","shop");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    function insert($statement) {
        global $con;
        mysqli_query($con,$statement);
    }
?>
```

When I print the statement out, the query is correct (I have verified this by manually copy pasting it in mysql). I think the issue is with my insert function.

Any help is appreciated,
thank you.

Comment: goto (C:\wamp\logs) and look for (error.log). It should tell you the error. Post the error if you cant resolve it

Comment: I'm wondering that if it's because you're on Windows (letter-case isn't like LINUX), that it may see `function Insert()` and `function insert($statement)` both being the same function and causing a conflict. I stand at being wrong, yet using similarly named functions have been known to cause havoc in the past; least from what I've seen before. Try renaming one of those functions and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Tried it, still does not work. Also the error log shows:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\new_list.php:0
new_list is the page on which the script is run

Comment: @user2883071 - is your code printing out the SQL statement (I assume so, since you're saying it looks like you expect it to)? Is it also printing out the `done`? Have you tried `mysqli_query($con,$statement) or echo mysqli_error($con)`?

Comment: Also, how are you calling `function Insert () {` from your JS script, there's no mention of in your code/question.

Comment: wow.. so the code is printing out the sql statement, HOWEVER, the error says No database selected- this is weird as it does not show in the logs, and I am including the database in the connect command
`$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","shop");`

Comment: You'd need to do `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","shop");` if there's no username and password; most likely the reason. As I mentioned in a now-deleted comment about what the manual states http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- that gives an error: access denied, failed to connect to database 'shop' - which is weird because it knows that the string 'shop' is the database

Comment: That's indeed strange.

Comment: Try using [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) see if that helps.

Comment: Figured it out, by default, the username is root, even though I am not prompted for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the username for mysql is root, and the password is blank, even though you aren't prompted for these, they are set by default.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, all mysql statements must end in a semicolon.

Secondly, have you made sure `$items` and `$description` are the values you expect them to have?  Do they have any unescaped quotes?

Also, typically you would send each of the fields as a separate value like so:

```
var item = document.getElementById('items').value;
var desc = document.getElementById('description').value;
XMLHttpRequestObject.send("items=" + item + "&desc=" + desc);


$$items = $_POST['items'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];
```

Comment: You don't need a semi-colon at the end when you're sending your SQL statement through PHP's `mysqli_` functions (ditto for `mysql_` and PDO)

Comment: Regarding the semicolon, it still does not make a difference. Even when I bundle them and send them together, I know they are going properly as when I print the statement out on the other php end, it prints out exactly as I had intended it to be sent. as I said, when I copy pasted the statement into mysql, it worked.

Comment: the semicolon is pretty only acceptable for multiple statements, you can just keep it out on only 1 statement!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the issue

in ur global variable `$con` letz say you put this

```
$con = new mysqli("host", "user", "pwd", "dbname");
```

then

```
function insert($statement) {
    $con->query($statement);
    $con->close();
}
```